# Function import list is empty for Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I've started work on an application that uses Entity Framework 5.0 and MVC 4 in VS 2012. The application connects to an existing database, so this is a database first site. So far things are working great. But I have a method i am writing that needs to use a function defined on the database side. Lets call it DoesItHaveAThingy(Guid id, string type), it returns a boolean. The function works fine, been working on this database for a few years.

So I open the edmx designer and right click then select Update Model From Database. I select my function and hit finish. It adds the funcion in Model.Store, you can see it in the model browser. Seems all good. Yet no code is generated.

I look about online and people say that once you have done that step you need to do Function Import. Ok, so i right click on the designer and hit Add -> Function import. It brings up the dialog where you an add your name for the function. The dialog also has a drop down list of functions, you need to select one. This is where the problem is, that drop down list is empty. So i can not import the function i need.

I'm guessing I am doing something wrong. I thought that maybe the emdx file added the function but with an error. I had that once with a view, checked the file, and near the view it had a comment stating the error for that view (it didnt have primary key, then again, what view does). But i didnt see any error message for the function, it seemed to be added ok.

Was it just that function? Nope, tried another function, same parameters yet returns an int. Same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: This might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx

Comment: @Pawel That didnt work. I tried creating a static function call and got the following error.

Comment: Lets try that again, damn enter button. The error was  The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean] DoesItHaveAThingy(System.Guid, System.String)' on the type 'OpenIdTest.Models.ModelExtensions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.  The function is  [EdmFunction("EDM", "DoesItHaveAThingy")]
        public static bool? DoesItHaveAThingy(Guid Id, string type)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Can not run this function in that way.");
        }   Could it be that what is linked does not work with Entity Framework 5.0?

Comment: Ok, I think i got it. As far as I can see Entity Framework does not support functions with a simple return. The function i use returns a bool (bit). That wont appear in the list. But a SP that selects some fields does. So i made a SP that wraps around the function and that appeared in the list just fine. Is there a way to actually get functions that return a simple type to work in EF? Also i found out after all this that EF would not support the call to the Fucntion/SP inside a LINQ command.

Comment: I had the same problem with the function not showing up in the function import.  I finally gave up and wrapped a stored proc around it.  All is well now.